# How to set the focus after a zone update in Tapestry5

Tags: tapestry

I have a zone that contains a form that contains a loop.  When someone changes a text field within the loop, it updates the entire form and loop on the onKeyUp event.

I am trying to find a way to tell Tapestry to return the focus to the text field that was last updated. I think I have this working, but the zone update appears to make the text field lose focus immediately after the focus is set. I can set the focus to a field that is outside of the zone without a problem, so it appears to be the zone update that is causing the issue.

Any suggestions on how to handle this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sounds like you need to set the focus after the zone is done reloading. Whenever I need to do a task like that I set up an observer that listens for the Tapestry zone-updated event in Javascript:

```
$('formZone').observe(Tapestry.ZONE_UPDATED_EVENT, function(event) {
    // set the focus
});
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 3):

The [Form](http://tapestry.apache.org/current/apidocs/org/apache/tapestry5/corelib/components/Form.html) component has an `autofocus` parameter which is true by default, causing a bit of JavaScript to be rendered with the form. The JS sets the focus to the first form element after the form has loaded.

Setting `autofocus` to `false` disables this behaviour:

```
<form t:type="Form" t:autofocus="false">
```

Comment: Thanks. I have actually tried it both ways and that doesn't seem to be the issue. I can set the focus to any field that is outside of the zone update without an issue.  It is just the ones in the zone that I can't get the cursor to stay active in.

Answer (score 3):

I know this is an old thread, but what I did was:

Using jquery:

```
<t:zone t:id="formZone">
<t:form .... class="formId" t:zone="formZone>
.
.
</t:form>

jQuery.noConflict();
(function($) { 
  $(document).ready(function() {
      $(".formId").find("input, select").filter(function(){
          if($(this).val() == ""){           
             return true;
          }
        }).first().focus();

  });
})(jQuery);


</t:zone>
```

This will get focus on first empty input or select. Of course you have to include jquery on your page. noConflict makes sure you wont have problems with prototype.